# How to get images from remote directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to make a gallery from directory using PHP. My gallery is working perfect but when I enable SEO urls it wont work

because the url to images/thumbnails changes

**from** `http://localhost/filemonoe-v2/admin/images/icons/88/screenshots-thumbs/Jellyfish.jpg` <<< This one is correct

**to** `http://localhost/filemono-v2/88/CCleaner-4-04-419-2/admin/images/icons/88/screenshots-thumbs/Jellyfish.jpg` <<< This one is wrong

I can see the path is wrong to image thats why its not showing in SEO enabled urls

Here is code of PHP to set directory path.

```
$images_dir = 'admin/images/icons/'.$id.'/screenshots/';
```

What I was thinking is to set baseUrl like

```
$baseurl='http://localhost/filemono-v2/';
$images_dir = ''.$baseurl.'admin/images/icons/'.$id.'/screenshots/';
```

But Its also not working with a baseUrl. I think By setting baseurl it asumes that directory is remote and dont know what should be the possible solution. I dont want to do change the code in such a way that if someone disables SEO urls from admin panel that gallery stops working without SEO url. I want to make it work in both conditions any idea guys ?

Here is my **.htaccess**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  #software urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ software-profile.php?pid=$1&slug=$2 [L]

  #browse urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ browse.php?page=$1&bid=$2&cat=$3 [L]

  #download urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ download.php?did=$1 [L]


  </IfModule>
```